# How to measure the weirdness of algorithms?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, reference-request, kolmogorov-complexity

Let $M$ is a polynomial $k$-tape Turing machine and $C^t(x)$ is a time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity.
Let $str_M(x)$ be a string of the following form:
$$str_M(x)=w_1^1\# w_2^1 \# ... \# w_{m}^1 ■ w_1^2 \# ... \# w_{m}^2 ■ ...■ w_1^k \# ... \# w_{m}^k ■$$
where $w_j^i$ is the content of tape $i$ at step $j$ at input $x$ of $M$, and $\#$ and ■ are delimiters.
Consider the following function, which we call the weirdness of $M$ :
$$W_M(n)=\max_{x\in \Sigma^n}C^t(str_M(x))$$
Here $t(n)$ is meant to depend on $T_M(n)$ in some natural way, for example $t(n)=T_M(n)$. Assuming $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$, what bounds hold for $W_M(n)$ if $M$ solves $\mathrm{NP}$-complete under log-space reductions problem? Does this measure correlate with an intuitive understanding of the strangeness of the algorithm?

General questions. What measures of "weirdness" of algorithms exist and have been studied?  In particular, are they based on Kolmogorov complexity? Have any lower bounds been proven for them?